# Having trouble pulling results by week in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, I have my information sorted by year, week#, and total (customers) in any given week.

```
=query({sort(IF(len(C2:C),{year(C2:C),weeknum(C2:C,14)},),1,true,2,true)},"Select Col1,Col2, Count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label Col1'Year', Col2'Week #',Count(Col1)'Total'",0)
```

I have two additional columns `(J:K)` that specify Yes/No and Pass/Fail for each row. I'd like to include a count of each column for "Yes" and "Pass" but i cannot wrap my head around how I can include these. I have tried adding

```
=query({sort(IF(len(C2:C),{year(C2:C),weeknum(C2:C,14)},),1,true,2,true);J2:K},"Select Col1,Col2, Count(Col1),Count(Col4) where Col1 is not null and Col4 = 'Yes' group by Col1,Col2 label Col1'Year', Col2'Week #',Count(Col1)'Total'",Count(Col4)'Yes',0)
```

To include the "YES" count, but I get a formula Parse Error.

Comment: Some sample data would be very helpful

Comment: Yes. Sample data would help a lot. But I also see that you did not close your QUERY in correct place. Your ending " should be after last 'Yes' but is after 'Total'.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look into [StackOverflow: How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to get a prompt response you can summarize the title and what's actually your expected code behavior. It's helpful for the community. Please provide more context so we can better understand your question.